# jqgrid add new row - pre-filled

Tags: jqgrid

I use two grids at one PHP page.
Is there any way to get data from the first grid (i.e. after click row) and pre-fill it into the add new row form in the second grid?
thank you for any suggestion Petr

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I correct understand what you mean under the "pre-filling". But how I understand you question you can do following:

With respect of [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event which you define on the first grid you will receive the id of selected row as the parameter. Inside of the [onSelectRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle you can call [getRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#methods) to get full information about the data of selected row. Then using [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods#methods) for example you can add new row in the second grid.